# How to install PostgreSQL 13 with Saltstacked state?

Tags: postgresql, salt-stack

The title is basically the question. I am using CentOS 8 and want to start using Saltstack states to install stuff like Postgresql-13, AdoptOpenJDK,...

```
    install-postgresql13-repository:
  cmd.run:
    - name: rpm -U --force https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

install-postgresql13-server:
  cmd.run:
    - name: dnf install postgresql13-server -y

postgresql-first-run-init:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-setup initdb
    - unless: stat /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/postgresql.conf
    - runas: root

start-postgresql13-server:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl start postgresql-13

enable-postgresql13-autostart:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl enable postgresql-13
```

but cmd.run is not the best option as far as i know.

Comment: The title is not a question. What are the problems you encounter?

Comment: As you said, using `cmd.run` is not the best option. It is like writing a `shell` script with Saltstack. It takes the "statefulness" away from Salt states. You could start with [readily available formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/postgres-formula) and reuse it if it suits your need.

Comment: Thank you @seshadri_c I will look up the formula. And I edited the title (so that it is a question now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit of using tool like Saltstack is the idempotence it offers by the way of "states".

Without getting into the complete solution, I would recommend you to go through [Salt states](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/).

For example the below code will run fine first time, but on second run it may give error. Even if it works, it is unnecessary.

```yaml
  cmd.run:
    - name: rpm -U --force https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

Whereas if you use a Salt state modules like below, they will be updated only when required. Subsequent runs will not attempt to make a change.

```yaml
install-postgresql13-repository:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
        - pgdg-redhat-repo: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

install-postgresql-server:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: postgresql13-server

# and similarly use salt states for other tasks where applicable
```